# Where do I set memory barriers so that conditional loops observe multithread value changes?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Assuming a thread running indefinitely until it's member variable stop is set. Like

```
while (!stop) {
  // do something
}
```

I want to prevent it turning into this

```
if (!stop) {
  while (true) {
  
  }
}
```

So where would I set memory barriers / fences so that this optimization can't be performed?
Also, would such a fence already be enough to ensure a change to `true` from another thread is visible in the next iteration?

Comment: `stop` should be `std::atomic`. With that, the compiler will insert the necessary barriers. Without that, the program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yes, but technically speaking, would the atomic place a memory barrier before or after the variable access. I thought memory barrier means the compiler can't reorder accesses before and/or after. But there's just that read on `stop`. So it technically isn't even reordered in regards to any other memory access

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it can be done without atomic, with `std::atomic_thread_fence` or conditional variables, but yes atomic should be the way to go as is the easiest and the less error prone.

Comment: @Regyn _"would the atomic place a memory barrier before or after the variable access"_ It would be ordered _with_ the memory access.  The access itself would behave like a memory fence.

Comment: @DrewDormann So the memory fence in e.g. atomic would force the compiler to not reorder the read so it's only performed once?

Comment: @Regyn: In your previous comment, you wrote: `"So the memory fence in e.g. atomic would force the compiler to not reorder the read so it's only performed once?"` The term "memory ordering" refers to the reordering of memory accesses in a single thread with other memory accesses of the same thread. Therefore, it does not make sense to use the word "reorder" in this context, because you are only talking about a single memory access of a thread. The issue at hand is not an issue of memory ordering, but rather of thread synchronization. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So where would I set memory barriers / fences so that this optimization can't be performed?

A [memory barrier/fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) restricts the [memory ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering), which prevents the compiler from reordering two or more memory accesses **in the same thread**. However, memory ordering is not the issue here, as you are only talking about a single memory access per thread.

Instead, you are talking about two memory operations on the same variable **from two different threads**. Therefore, this is a matter of [thread synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization), not memory ordering.

According to [§6.9.2.2 ¶21 of the ISO C++20 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.multithread#intro.races-21), if two threads access the same variable without a synchronization operation (e.g. mutex) in between, and if these memory accesses are not

1. both atomic, or
2. both read-only,

then this results in undefined behavior.

Therefore, in the case of your `while` loop

```
while (!stop) {
  // do something
}
```

assuming that `stop` is a non-atomic data type, the compiler is allowed to assume that the variable `stop` will never be modified by another thread while the loop is running (unless you happen to have a synchronization operation inside the loop), because doing so would result in undefined behavior (which means that the compiler would be allowed to do anything).

For this reason, a good optimizing compiler will effectively change the code to the following:

```
if (!stop) {
  while (true) {  
    // do something
  }
}
```

However, if you change the variable `stop` to an atomic data type, such as [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) or [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), then it is not undefined behavior for several threads to access this variable at the same time. In that case, the compiler will not be allowed to assume that `stop` will not be modified by another thread, so that it will not be allowed to perform the optimization mentioned above.

Comment: What I’m wondering is: what construct does atomic bool to indicate there’s something happening that might modify the variable and therefore prevent the optimization. Is the compiler checking for atomic and identifying it has such side effects?

Comment: @Regyn: When a variable is atomic, the compiler is aware of this, and will make all reads and writes to that variable atomic operations. The compiler is aware that an atomic variable can be modified at any time by a different thread. Therefore, the compiler knows that it is not allowed to optimize away a read or a write to an atomic variable. There is no need to explicitly tell the compiler that the atomic variable may be modified by a different thread. This is already implied by declaring the variable as atomic (i.e. by using `std::atomic_flag` or `std::atomic`).

Answer (score 2):

It's a short one and has been told in comments, but the answer is:

```
std::atomic<bool> stop;
```

Let the compiler deal with fences.

Comment: Yep. A memory fence is both too much and too little for your application, so it will needlessly harm performance without guaranteeing the behavior you need. It's too little because it has no visibility guarantees. It's too much because it imposes ordering constraints on all other memory accesses.

Answer (score 0):

As it's already been answered, a simple:

```
std::atomic<bool> stop;
```

suffices, as [operations on atomic variables are ordered in a sequentially-consistent manner](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

However, release semantics could be used on stores and acquire semantics on loads to a similar effect:

```
bool side_effects = false;
std::atomic<bool> stop = false;

std::thread do_stop(
    [&]
    {
        side_effects = true;
        stop.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    });

while(!stop.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
{
}

// Any side effect ordered before the release store is necessarily
// visible after such store is sensed by the acquire load.
assert((side_effects));

do_stop.join();
```

See it [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e99e2f78b71c1c29).